# Postgresql 8.4 and BitDefender 11

Tags: database, windows, installation, antivirus

Since I've change my antivirus to BitDefender 11 I cannot start Postgresql 8.4 on my desktop (command line or service alike). Browsing on the Internet is seems that is a known issue, since many people are complaining about this issue
Does anyone know a workaround to this issue?
Thanks

Peter

Comment: Please provide more details about the errors that you're getting.  This would be better to raise on serverfault than SO, btw.

Comment: For '>pg_ctl -D "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\8.4\data" -w start' I am getting: 'could not map view of backend variables: error code 6'. Disabling modules in BitDefender (such as antivirus and firewall' does not seem to change the behavior. Also adding rules for Postgresql has no effect either

Answer (score 0):

As a note, this was asked on the mailing list and was responded to by Tom Lane (http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/26791.1290036551@sss.pgh.pa.us).

Apparently this is cause by BitDefender interfering with file access.   If updating to the latest version of the software doesn't fix the problem, time to switch to a different anti-virus.